# Undefined references when linking gsl library in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gsl

I'm trying to link an open source project that uses GSL and I get undefined references in libgsl. I'm using eclipse and I've added -lgslcblas -lgsl to the libraries setting. What am I missing?

```
g++ -L/home/erwin/ochack/bin/opencog/spatial -L/home/erwin/ochack/bin/opencog/persist/sql -L/home/erwin/ochack/bin/opencog/guile -L/home/erwin/ochack/bin/opencog/util -L/home/erwin/ochack/bin/opencog/persist/xml -o "ocserver"  ./opencog/server/Agent.o ./opencog/server/BaseServer.o ./opencog/server/BuiltinRequestsModule.o ./opencog/server/CogServer.o ./opencog/server/CogServerMain.o ./opencog/server/ConsoleSocket.o ./opencog/server/DataRequest.o ./opencog/server/ExitRequest.o ./opencog/server/HelpRequest.o ./opencog/server/ListRequest.o ./opencog/server/LoadModuleRequest.o ./opencog/server/LoadRequest.o ./opencog/server/NetworkServer.o ./opencog/server/Request.o ./opencog/server/SaveRequest.o ./opencog/server/ServerSocket.o ./opencog/server/ShutdownRequest.o ./opencog/server/SleepRequest.o ./opencog/server/SystemActivityTable.o ./opencog/server/UnloadModuleRequest.o  ./opencog/atomspace/Atom.o ./opencog/atomspace/AtomSpace.o ./opencog/atomspace/AtomSpaceAsync.o ./opencog/atomspace/AtomSpaceImpl.o ./opencog/atomspace/AtomSpaceInit.o ./opencog/atomspace/AtomTable.o ./opencog/atomspace/AttentionBank.o ./opencog/atomspace/AttentionValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/ClassServer.o ./opencog/atomspace/CompositeTruthValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/CountTruthValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/FixedIntegerIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/Handle.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleEntry.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleIterator.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleSeqIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleSet.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleTemporalPair.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleTemporalPairEntry.o ./opencog/atomspace/HandleToTemporalEntryMap.o ./opencog/atomspace/ImportanceIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/IndefiniteTruthValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/Link.o ./opencog/atomspace/LinkIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/NameIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/Node.o ./opencog/atomspace/NodeIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/NullTruthValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/PredicateIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/SimpleTruthValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/SpaceServer.o ./opencog/atomspace/StatisticsMonitor.o ./opencog/atomspace/StringIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/TLB.o ./opencog/atomspace/TargetTypeIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/Temporal.o ./opencog/atomspace/TemporalEntry.o ./opencog/atomspace/TemporalMap.o ./opencog/atomspace/TemporalTable.o ./opencog/atomspace/TemporalToHandleSetMap.o ./opencog/atomspace/TimeServer.o ./opencog/atomspace/Trail.o ./opencog/atomspace/TruthValue.o ./opencog/atomspace/TypeIndex.o ./opencog/atomspace/VersionHandle.o ./opencog/atomspace/ZMQMessages.pb.o   -lboost_filesystem -lpersist -lsmob -lgslcblas -lgsl -lboost_signals -lboost_thread -lxml -lutil -lSpaceMap -lzmq -lboost_system -lprotobuf
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zher2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_strsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zdotc_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dtrsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zhemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_strmm'
```

etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution: apparently the order of the libraries is important: -lgsl -lgslcblas works.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, there are lots of things that could be wrong here.

1. Have you made sure that you've added the libraries properly in Eclipse? For instance, you shouldn't specify `-lgsl` in *Paths and Symbols -> Libraries*. Eclipse adds the preceding `-l` itself so all you specify is `gsl`.
2. Have you added the library paths in the build variant that you're actually trying to run? You may, for instance, have specified library paths only for the Debug variant when you're trying to get a Release variant build going.

Alternatively, (and this is really just a guess), it's reasonably common for scientific libraries to allow you to use an external version of BLAS. Sometimes their configuration settings even insist on external BLAS as a default. Does passing `-lcblas` as a link option help out with these errors?

Comment: I've entered the libraries correctly and for the right build variant (see the link command). I don't know about cblas i don't have it on my machine and i've never seen it mentioned just -lgslcblas -lgsl.